# How to propagate error back to previous layer in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, cnn

I have a convolutional layer [**(link)**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CdqYkHYYXox0QDzfC-uIKgwQA_ZWbMUUiVg5pJ3_j2s/edit#gid=0) with an input **5x5x2** (width, height, depth):

The layer has 3 filters with dimensions **3x3x2**, it produces an output with dimensions **3x3x3**.

I have completed the forward pass:

[image: Forward Pass]

In a backward pass I calculated gradients of weights $dL/dw$, but I am not sure how to calculate $dL/dh$ (gradients for the previous layer).

[image: Backward Pass]

First or all, is my calculation of $dL/dw$ valid ? (please refer to external spread sheet linked to the question) And most importantly, how do I propagate deltas to the previous layer ?

Comment: Have a look at Jeremy Howard's Excel file hosted publicly on GitHub..He had simulated A CNN in EXCEL ITSELF..

Comment: @Aditya Thank you, would you mind to share a link ?

Comment: Here you go https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fastai/fastai/tree/master/courses/dl1/excel/

Comment: @Aditya, thank you! It is very useful link, but unfortunately it does not cover backpropagation in CNN.

Comment: What is $L$ in this question?

Comment: Exactly, the question is missing some details as to what's the architecture, activation functions etc

Comment: @JahKnows errors passed back from a next layer

Comment: @Aditya What exactly is missing ? Convolutional layer in my example does not have activation function.

Comment: @Aditya, sorry what difference does it make ? I do not care about other layers. I care about that particular layer. During the backward pass it receives gradients from the next layer and has to pass it back to the previous layer.

Comment: Added the answer as images, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since calculating the backward gradients that too in CNN is very math heavy and it's a bit different from normal MLP as in CNN'S we have Tensors not scalar values to multiply so People use Correlation to Calculate the Convolution Operation...

Just adding some links which I refer to from time to time thinking that someday I will be able to do this from scratch (seems impossible with deepening of Layers though...)

- [Reference 1](http://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/)
- [Reference 2](https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199)
- `CS231N Slides (Lecture 4-6 specially, the computational graphs construction are very helpful to understand the Back-propagation Algorithm..)`

It would be great if Someone can `transfer the Equations into Latex here`
So that the question can be answered formally..

Based on the above Links, here's what I got,(Came to know that Convolutions are equivalent to Correlation)

[Image 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/172Ymua0dKPMtmUpPqARWdsCU5C96N-C5/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Image 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VUNu_71bMSlxLCAh-jzLtAH2pBG9193Q/view?usp=drivesdk)

*Stack doesn't allow me uploading image so using gdrive..(do rotate one of the images, the first one actually)*

Hope it will give you an idea...

Comment: I am a student so no sir please. really liked your idea of manually calculating the gradients, Thanks

Comment: Problem is solved?

Comment: Thank you, It is much clear for me now. If you ever visit Toronto, round of beer on me.