# How do I calculate the partial derivative with respect to x?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, backpropagation

I am trying to implement **CNN** using python Numpy.
 
I searched so much, but all I found was for one filter with one channel for Convolution.

Suppose we have an **X** as Image with this shape: `(N_Height, N_Width, N_Channel) = (5,5,3)`

And Let's say I have `16` filters with this shape: `(F_Height, F_Width, N_Channel) = (3,3,3)` , `stride=1` and `padding=0`

**Forward**:

Output shape after conv2d will be

`(`
`math.floor((N_Height - F_Height + 2*padding)/stride + 1 )),`
`math.floor((N_Width- F_Width + 2*padding)/stride + 1 )),`
`filter_count`
`)`

So the output of this layer will be an array with this shape: `(Height, Width, Channel) =  (3, 3, 16)`

**BackPropagation**:

Suppose $dL/dh$ is the input for my layer in backpropagation with this shape: `(3,3,16)`

Now I must find $dL/dw$ and $dL/dx$: $dL/dw$ to update my filters params and $dL/dx$ to pass it as input to the previous layer as Loss respect to the input **X**.

From this answer [Error respect to filters weights](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/45978/89170) I found how to calculate $dL/dw$.

The problem I have in **BackPropagation** is I don't know how to calculate $dL/dx$ having this shape:`(5,5,3)` and pass it to the prev layer.

I read lots of articles in Medium and other sites but I don't get how to calculate it:

[How Backpropagation works in a CNN](https://medium.com/@pavisj/convolutions-and-backpropagations-46026a8f5d2c)
[The best explanation of Convolutional Neural Networks on the Internet!](https://medium.com/technologymadeeasy/the-best-explanation-of-convolutional-neural-networks-on-the-internet-fbb8b1ad5df8)
[Backpropagation In Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/)
[How to propagate error back to previous layer in CNN?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28593/how-to-propagate-error-back-to-previous-layer-in-cnn?rq=1)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This might help: http://cbelwal.blogspot.com/2018/05/part-i-backpropagation-mechanics-for.html

Comment: Unfortunately not